# onSaveInstanceState() in fragment is called even if the fragment doesn't appear using navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am using the navigation component and I have a problem that I don't know why it happens.

I am using `onSaveInstanceState()` in a `Fragment` and when I change the fragment that the navigation component displays, when I rotate the screen onSaveInstanceState() of the previous fragment is executed.

Why does it happens? This fragment should be destroyed and it shouldn't execute the method.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not destroyed when they are in the back stack - only the Fragment's **view** is destroyed. This is the key difference between the fragment lifecycle and the Fragment's view lifecycle (of `getViewLifecycleOwner()`).

While the Fragment's view state is saved automatically before the view is destroyed, it is still the responsibility of the fragment to save any fragment specific state when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.